# How to execue PHP scripts in the background using EXEC() and CMD

Tags: php, windows, cmd, windows-console

I can't use the `$com = new Com('WScript.shell');` way, it's causing problems on my system. Probably I need to upgrade my PHP because it's very old (5.2), but I suppose what I'm trying to do is not version dependent.

I'm running PHP on Windows 2008 64-bit. Where I can run a command prefixed with `start` to run the command on a separate console.

```
start php myscript.php
```

If this is executed from the command line, it starts a new console for the script.

I need to do the same from PHP using [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) **only**.

```
exec("CMD /C start php myscript.php");
```

`/C` is to terminate the CMD session when the script finishes.

But it's not giving the same results, it still waits for the script to terminate !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shoul work:

```
exec("start /B php myscript.php");
```

Also close all standard streams at the very beginning of myscript.php:

```
fclose(STDIN);
fclose(STDOUT);
fclose(STDERR);
```

If you want `echo` to still work, you can open a file for writing to stdout after closing the standard streams:

```
$STDIN = fopen('/dev/null', 'r');
$STDOUT = fopen('myscript.log', 'wb');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the `start /B` perfectly. But what are the other `fclose` statements ?! I'm not a PHP dev btw :)

Comment: Windows would not let program go to background unless it closes all 3 standard streams.

Comment: Will this affect file logging or `echo` statements ?

Comment: File logging no, but echo statements yes - there's no stdout anymore. I'll update the answer with another solution.

Comment: Thank you. But what replaces `/dev/null` for windows machines ?

Comment: On windows it's `nul`

Comment: `fclose` statements did nothing for me, but `nul` did the trick!